# How to use ipsec on a LAN without vpn

Tags: ipsec

Is it possible to transfer data between computers (Windows 7) in a LAN using IPSEC (for authentication and encryption) but without VPN? If yes how? All the information I found related to possible solutions include VPN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the best site I found related to the question:
http://www.it.cornell.edu/services/managed_servers/howto/ipsec.cfm